# how to test if variables exists in function with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, this

I am writing Unit-Tests for a Class looking like this:

```
class example {

    public function __construct($param1, $param2) {
        $this->param1 = $param1
        $this->param2 = $param2
    }
}
```

Is it possible to test if $this->param1 and $this->param2 exists after the constructor is executed? I already googled for this but didn't found a valid answer to this. I tried it with the [Assertion contain](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains), but this didn't work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see whether properties have been assigned the specified values in the resulting object, use [Reflection class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php). In your example, if you properties are public:

```
public function testInitialParams()
{
    $value1 = 'foo';
    $value2 = 'bar';
    $example = new Example($value1, $value2); // note that Example is using 'Standing CamelCase'
    $sut = new \ReflectionClass($example);

    $prop1 = $sut->getProperty('param1');
    $prop1->setAccessible(true); // Needs to be done to access protected and private properties
    $this->assertEquals($prop2->getValue($example), $value1, 'param1 got assigned the correct value');

    $prop2 = $sut->getProperty('param2');
    $prop2->setAccessible(true);
    $this->assertEquals($prop2->getValue($example), $value2, 'param2 got assigned the correct value');
}
```

Comment: This dont works, got this Errormessage: is not instance of expected class "ReflectionProperty"

Comment: Oops, wait for a fix :-)

Comment: @nova This works. Forgot that it's not that simple when working with reflections.

Comment: $this->assertEquals($sut->getProperty('param1')->getValue($example), $value1, 'param1 got assigned the correct value'); still does not work only prop2

Comment: As mentioned in the adjacent answer, it depends on the visibility type of your properties. If `$param1` is protected/private, then `->setAccessible(true);` is necessary for getting access to those properties.

Comment: I know, could you remove or edit this line? then ill mark your answer as correct and thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124215/discussion-between-bvengerov-and-nova).

Answer (score 4):

There is an assertion `assertAttributeSame()` that allows you to look at public, protected and private properties of a class.

See the example:

```
class ColorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
public function test_assertAttributeSame() {

    $hasColor = new Color();

    $this->assertAttributeSame("red","publicColor",$hasColor);
    $this->assertAttributeSame("green","protectedColor",$hasColor);
    $this->assertAttributeSame("blue","privateColor",$hasColor);

    $this->assertAttributeNotSame("wrong","privateColor",$hasColor);
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, these methods were deprecated in PHPUnit 8 and will be removed in PHPUnit 9.

Comment: @duncan - Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared any visibility on `$this->param1` or `$this->param2`, so by default they will be public.

With this in mind, you ought to just be able to test like the following:

```
public function testConstructorSetsParams()
{
    $param1 = 'testVal1';
    $param2 = 'testVal2';

    $object = new example($param1, $param2);

    $this->assertEquals($param1, $object->param1);
    $this->assertEquals($param2, $object->param2);
}
```

Comment: Cannot access non-public member, you need to set them accessible first

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Have you set any visibility restrictions on the properties?